# Enable SSO for Windows server 2016

Tags: xml, single-sign-on, adfs, on-premises-instances

We have Web Application created in Angular 12. This web application is targeted for only Organizational users.The Web Application is hosted on IIS web Server (running on Windows Server 2016 - Onpremise).Requirement is to enable SSO for the above hosted web application.
Customer's AD management team mentioned that they can enable SSO for the Website via Onpremise ADFS.
They would need Metadata XML for the Web Application, to enable SSO.
Can you help with below-
How to fetch Metadata XML for Angular Application deployed on IIS web Server?
Is there any alternate way to enable SSO for the Angular Application hosted on IIS web server?
For SSO enablement, do we have to select Windows Authentication option from IIS server Authentication list?

Answer (score 0):

For an application to talk to ADFS, it needs to support one of these protocols:

- WS-Federation
- SAML 2.0
- OpenID Connect

So you need a client-side protocol stack. Normally for Angular, you would use OIDC. This does not have metadata. You just create an application manually in ADFS.

Sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs).

Note: ADAL is being deprecated at some point but its successor MSAL only works on  ADFS 2019.